# Может кто нибудь объяснить смысл зачем так делают?

Tags: php, node.js

Занимаюсь разработкой чата на NodeJs для интереса выбрал произвольные сайты, где есть реализация websocket. Дабы посмотреть для себя как это делают другие. На одном ресурсе реализация такая:
1. Клиент посылает в PHP GET запрос. PHP собирает данные из БД информацию о клиенте.
2. Из PHP отправляется на сервер NodeJs websocket-У
Для чего так сделано?

Пример:
NodeJs Server

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/phpcallback', function(req, res) {
    var content = req.body;
    console.log('Отправлено из php: ' + content.msg);
    //Отправляем в сокет
    res.end('ok');
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
    var addr = http.address();
    console.log('Сервер запущен на' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port);
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

$data = array("name" => "Robot", "msg" => "Сообщение из PHP");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/phpcallback');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

echo curl_exec($ch)."\n";
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Какой смысл в этом всем?
Не проще авторизировать клиента уже на сервере NodeJs объекту ws отдать данные из БД и уже работать с этими данными, для обмена сообщениями? Какой смысл использовать PHP и Ajax запрос для отправки сообщений?
В чем логика?

Comment: Тут нету веб-сокета. Тут обычный сокет

Comment: @ArchDemon Я как пример привел этот код суть не в этом

Comment: Если у вас сервисная архитектура, то неважно какой язык программирования вы выберите для каждого отдельно сервиса. В том числе и для клиента. Если такое делается в рамках одного сервиса, то это скорее извращение или неумение работать с языком программирования сервера

Comment: @ArchDemon Так я тоже в недоумении зачем? Вот и вопрос задал может есть хоть какой-то смысл в этом))) Мне просто очень интересно для чего так сделали))))

Comment: @ArchDemon Полез посмотреть как на клиенте send.message() Делается с тем подходом может у себя как то по лучше сделать)))) Смотрю нет отправки сообщений. Начал разбираться обнаружил что через GET запрос который в PHP отправляется приходит сообщение в сокет))) Думаю мож есть какой смысл вот и вопрос задал